# Youtube Views | Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, youtube

I am trying to help Tariqh with this video but I keep getting all sorts of errors
I have looked through all similar questions and nothing helped

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
d = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YSoJPA8-oHc'

driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal Bandies/chromedriver.exe')
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal Bandies/chromedriver.exe')
driver3 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal Bandies/chromedriver.exe')

driver1.get(url)
driver2.get(url)
driver3.get(url)

while True:
    driver1.refresh
    driver2.refresh
    driver3.refresh
```

I get the following errors

> ```
> [3472:13232:0422/235523.116:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [23:55:23.117] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1075 Getting
> ```
>
> Default Adapter failed.
>
> ```
> ====== WebDriver manager ======
> Current google-chrome version is 100.0.4896
> Get LATEST chromedriver version for 100.0.4896 google-chrome
> Driver [C:\Users\Juan\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\100.0.4896.60\chromedriver.exe]
> ```
>
> found in cache
>
> ```
> ====== WebDriver manager ======
> Current google-chrome version is 100.0.4896
> Get LATEST chromedriver version for 100.0.4896 google-chrome
> Driver [C:\Users\Juan\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\100.0.4896.60\chromedriver.exe]
> ```
>
> found in cache
>
> ```
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal Bandies/YoutubeTiktok.py", line 10
>     d = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
> DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
>
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal Bandies/YoutubeTiktok.py", line 14
>     driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal
> ```
>
> Bandies/chromedriver.exe')
> DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
>
> ```
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal Bandies/YoutubeTiktok.py", line 15
>     driver2 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal
> ```
>
> Bandies/chromedriver.exe')
> DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
>
> ```
> Warning (from warnings module):
>   File "C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal Bandies/YoutubeTiktok.py", line 16
>     driver3 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal
> ```
>
> Bandies/chromedriver.exe')
> DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 703, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 449, in _make_request
> six.raise_from(e, None)
> File "", line 3, in raise_from
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 444, in _make_request
> httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py",
> line 1374, in getresponse
> response.begin()
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py",
> line 318, in begin
> version, status, reason = self._read_status()
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py",
> line 279, in _read_status
> line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py",
> line 705, in readinto
> return self._sock.recv_into(b)
> ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>
> ```
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/Juan/Documents/Illegal Bandies/YoutubeTiktok.py", line 19, in <module>
>     driver2.get(url)
>   File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> ```
>
> line 437, in get
> self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 423, in execute
> response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py",
> line 333, in execute
> return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py",
> line 355, in _request
> resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py",
> line 78, in request
> return self.request_encode_body(
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\request.py",
> line 170, in request_encode_body
> return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py",
> line 376, in urlopen
> response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 785, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py",
> line 550, in increment
> raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py",
> line 769, in reraise
> raise value.with_traceback(tb)
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 703, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 449, in _make_request
> six.raise_from(e, None)
> File "", line 3, in raise_from
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py",
> line 444, in _make_request
> httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py",
> line 1374, in getresponse
> response.begin()
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py",
> line 318, in begin
> version, status, reason = self._read_status()
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py",
> line 279, in _read_status
> line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
> File "C:\Users\Juan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py",
> line 705, in readinto
> return self._sock.recv_into(b)
> urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly
> closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

I would love to also add proxies cycle but I can't at this stage of my skill. If you do the extra effort thank you I am thankful.